# Sigma question: is it legal to write something like this?

Tags: notation

Is this mathematical syntax correct?

$$\sum_{n+1}^m\sin(n-2)
$$

As you see, the starting value is $n+1$ instead of being just purely one variable.

Comment: It may even be legal, depends on the judge. But it is a really bad idea to use $n$ as the (presumed) summation index, and also as a component of one of the ends. If I am reading your intent correctly, I would write something like $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n+1}^m \sin(i-2)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{n+1}^m\sin(n-2)$$

What is the running index here? Apparently $\,n\,$ , but from what number does it begin running? Perhaps it should be $\,n=1\,$ in the summatory's lower limit?

As it stands, the expression makes not much sense.

Comment: what i want to mean is for the sum start at n+1

Comment: @user1561559 yes sure. But summand is always prametrized. In your case it *must* be $n$ as otherwise doesnt make sense. If $m>n+1$, you can define such but I am not sure if it makes sense...

Comment: @user1561559 Then you probably want $$\sum_{i=n+1}^m\sin(i-2)$$ unless the expression you are going for is equal to $(m-n-1)\sin(n-2)$.

Answer (score 3):

If there's any doubt about what the index of summation is, then specify it explicitly.  If you write about the sum of terms called $\sin(n-2)$, then commonplace conventions make the reader think $n$ goes from something to something.  But you've used $n$ as one of the bounds, meaning $n$ stays put while some other variable goes from $n+1$ to $m$, and what that other variable, the index, is called (is it $i$? is it $k$?) you don't say.  If you write
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^m \sin(n-2),
$$
then that's
$$
\sin(n-2)+\sin(n-2)+\sin(n-2)+\cdots+\sin(n-2)
$$
and all terms are identical, and there are $m-n$ of them, so the sum is $(m-n)\sin(n-2)$.  If you meant anything other than that, then don't use this notation.

Comment: IMO, the index of summation should be specified explicitly even when there can't really be any doubt – really, it's just one symbol! The _range_ over which that variable is summed, which may be rather more awkward to write, may be well be left out if it's clear from the context like in $\langle a, b \rangle = \sum_i a_i\!\cdot\!b_i$. (Which, of course, you might write simply $a_ib_i$, following Einstein convention...)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your notation is not good. The reason is that it isn't clear what the index of summation is. From how it is written it looks like $m$ and $n$ might both be constants. But then you only have the variable $n$ after the summation sign, so one would think that $n$ is what is "changing" in the summation. But if you want the sum to start at $n+1$, then you should write something like (as mentioned in the comments and the other answer): 
$$
\sum_{i = n+1}^m \sin(i-2).
$$
What this means is the sum
$$
\sin(n+1-2) + \sin(n+2-2) + \dots +\sin(m-1-2) + \sin(m-2).
$$
You could IMO get away with writing this same sum as
$$
\sum_{n+1}^m \sin(i-2).
$$